# how can i hide ID in URL with asp.net MVC4

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

My URL

> http://www.domain.com/Products/{Alias}-{ID}

and my route

```
routes.MapRoute(
               name: "ProductDetail",
               url: "Products/{Alias}-{detailId}",
               defaults: new { controller = "Products", action = "ProductDetail", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

In controller

```
public ActionResult ProductDetail(int? detailId)
        {
            var pro = db.Products.Find(detailId);
            if (pro == null)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "NotFound");
            }
            return View(pro);
        }
```

Now, I want to hide ID in my URL like

> http://www.domain.com/Products/{Alias}

How can i do that

Comment: What do you mean hide it? If you don't add it to the url, you wont get it in the controller.

Comment: If the `Alias` is unique to a product then you can just drop the id completely and use that instead, but only if you are sure it will be unique. Perhaps it would help if you explained *why* you want to hide it as there might be other ways to get what you are trying to achieve

Comment: @StephenMuecke if i don't add detailID in the URL, so how to get detailID in controller?

Comment: @musefan, OP would need to add a parameter in the method for that (its completely useless in the route as it is)

Comment: @StephenMuecke: Yeah of course

Comment: @TienKenji: Are you just joking around now? If you don't pass the `detailID` you can't get the `detailID`, how would you expect to get something that doesn't exist?

Comment: You cant (unless your posting form data). Also `id = UrlParameter.Optional` is a bit pointless - you don't have a parameter named `id`. And you don't have a parameter for `{alias}` either

Answer (score 11):

**Short Answer**

It is not possible to do what you want. In that if you want to be able to access the `detailId` from your controller the you must pass the `detailId` as part of your URL - you cannot access something that does not exist.

---

**Long Answer**

There are other ways to get around 'hiding' the `detailId` from the user, and here are some suggestions:

**1. Use Alias instead:**

You can remove `detailId` all together and use the `Alias` value instead. This however will require the `Alias` value to be unique to the product you are trying to query, and the required changes might look like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    //..
    url: "Products/{Alias}",
    //..
);

public ActionResult ProductDetail(string Alias)
{
    var pro = db.Products.FindByAlias(Alias);
    //...
}
```

**2. Use a POST request:**

Another solution that will effectively hide the `detailId` from the URL but still allow the value to be passed to the controller would be to use a POST request, where the parameter value would be specified in the POST request body.

The drawback of this however is that you cannot simply provide a URL for the user to click, and coding links within your site takes considerably more effort. Typically with MVC, POST request occur when a form is submitted, and you can also do POST request with javascript ajax calls.

This is a bit too much to go into in this answer so if you are interested then do some research, such as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8495706/mvc-html-actionlink-with-post-functionality), or some generally [info here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14551194/how-are-parameters-sent-in-an-http-post-request).

**3. Encrypt the detailId value:**

Now this options doesn't hide the `detailId` from the URL, but if your concern is that the current ID is just too user friendly then you could 'encrypt' (used loosely) the value. For example you could convert to a base64 string, and then back to an int within your controller. This would give you a URL something like this:

```
http://www.domain.com/Products/{Alias}-MQ%3D%3D
```

This URL represents `1` as the `detailId` and you have to be ensure to [URL encode/decode](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp) your values if using this method.

In this instance, Base64 conversion isn't really 'encrypting' it, any semi-savvy user will notice this and could get around it. But you could just as easily use a more secure 2-way encryption algorithm if you wanted to take this approach, one where only the server knows the encryption/decryption key. The drawback here is that only the server will be able to produce valid URLs for your users to 'click on'.

---

At this point it is worth considering that if your concern is that the URL is too user friendly by including a simple numeric ID, then the question is: why do you care?

If you are worried the user could simply change the `detailId` value and then have access to products they should have access to, then you have a bigger problem with security. If this is the case, then your controller should be responsibly for validating is the user has access to the product they are trying to access, and then act accordingly.

All security checking and validation should be handled server-side, never rely on your client code or user actions to do it for you.